# Is this and prototypical inheritance better for performance than direct references?

Tags: javascript, this, prototype

Is it better to do this...

```
var obj1 = {
    a: function(){...}
}
var obj2 = Object.assign(Object.create(obj1),{
    b: function(){ this.a(); }
});
obj2.b();
```

or...

```
var obj1 = {
    a: function(){...}
}
var obj2 = {
    b: function(){ obj1.a(); }
});
obj2.b();
```

I'm building a webapp mostly with the first pattern, but I'm starting to question if the performance impact of using 'this' is really worth the extra step.

Sorry if this is dumb or been posted before, I'm still trying to wrap my head around the idea of prototypal inheritance and it's all really confusing

Comment: Both of those code snippets will produce a syntax error because a semicolon can't appear inside of an object literal like that. Could you make the code clearer?

Comment: ...And, `obj1.a()` returns whatever the function returns, but you haven't set up an object property (key) to store it, as in `var obj2 = { someKey: obj1.a() }`

Comment: Its not performance but rather a menory thing

Comment: oups yeah it's just a brainfart haha I meant something more  b: function(){ obj1.a():} I'll correct it in an edit

Comment: To the close voters: this question is not opinion-based. It is searching for a yes/no answer and a convincing motivation. Hence it should stay open.

Comment: Both codes perform different things now. So a comparison is useless. (Hint: `console.log(this)}`)

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist Searching for a yes/no answer when there is none isn't justification to keep the question open. This is an opinion based answer.

Comment: The asker is asking which method is best **for performance** and not which is best in general. The answer provided by Eleazor Enrique (his answer is no) is correct.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist And, here come the opinions. I say there is a difference (albeit minimal) because working with inheritance means working with the prototype chain to look up property values. This process doesn't happen when you don't use inheritance. All of this also depends on what user-agent we are talking about. Hence, there is not a yes/no answer.

Comment: It is clear from the context that the asker isn't concerned with semantic differences. Yes, obviously Javascript performance is determined by the web-browser.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist And, the prototype chain has no performance implications?

Comment: @ScottMarcus: No, in a modern js vm it likely hasn't. One can know for sure by bench-marking. No opinions involved...

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist That was a rhetorical question. of course there are performance implications in searching through a set of objects for the one that has a property. Are those implications significant? No, probably not, but since we can't know what user-agents the public uses, the difference requires us to consider it. The point is that there is no simple "yes/no" answer here.

Comment: @ScottMarcus There is (no). Your argument if taken to its logical conclusion would mean that **no question** about performance is on topic for SO, since we can't know the exact hardware, os, compiler or runtime someone is using. In the real world, one therefore makes the assumption "operating under normal circumstances" because that is the interesting scenario. In this case, the correct answer is "No, it doesn't matter one bit" which both Eleazor Enrique and you wrote.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist *Your argument if taken to its logical conclusion would mean that no question about performance is on topic for SO* That is absolutely and demonstrably incorrect. We can say with certainty that performing work is more resource intensive than not performing work. We can also say with certainty that certain types of work will perform better than other types. We can say both of these things without needing to know any details about the implementation. Doing lookups along the prototype chain (doing something) will never be as efficient as not doing those lookups (doing nothing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, your syntax is wrong, so neither will work.

But, your question really is simply "Is inheritance better than not using inheritance". The fact that JS uses prototypical inheritance really isn't the issue.

And, the answer is going to be based on opinions, so here's mine.

Inheritance is better because the code becomes more flexible and less brittle. Brittle code is always something to be avoided in software designs. Does it add more complexity to the code? Sure, but don't confuse complexity with readability. It seems that many developers shy away from more complex code in the name of "this is harder to read and follow", when that shouldn't be a litmus test for your code in the first place. Code patterns do often add additional layers of complexity and redirection to the code base, but what you gain is a more flexible code base that can adapt to change.

The use of `this` isn't going to affect performance at all because `this` is an automatically assigned object reference that will happen whether you use it or not. And, it's just a copy of a memory address, not a copy of the object itself.

From a performance standpoint, given the optimizations that modern user-agents employ, you are unlikely to notice any appreciable difference, but the inheritance mode is, by its very nature, going to require more from the runtime as the prototype-chain becomes a factor.

Answer (score 2):

## The two approaches are equals in terms of performance.

The difference between them is *scalability* according to the number of objects you will need to create using the `Object.create` function cause every call of `Object.create` will create an additional instance. So, we don't have to mix *performance* and *scalability*.

On the other hand, for me it's cleaner the Inheritance because provide more **readable and organized code**, so you're already **gaining time in future maintenance**.